# Creating master view in Windows Phone application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I am creating a MasterView within which all the views will navigate for this I have created a Simple Xaml page and added a TransitionFrame within it then navigating the other pages within this frame. But when my application start and it navigates to MasterView it crashes with following error:

ERROR:

```
{System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: Cannot create instance of type 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls.TransitionFrame' [Line: 32 Position: 22] ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame..ctor()
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.TransitionFrame..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at View.MasterView.InitializeComponent()
   at View.MasterView..ctor()}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <toolkit:TransitionFrame
            x:Name="MasterFrame"
            Grid.Row="1" >

        </toolkit:TransitionFrame>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Can you show your XAML usings statement for toolkit?

Comment: What happens if you do this insetead?          <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <toolkit:TransitionFrame
            x:Name="MasterFrame"
            Grid.Row="1" />

Comment: @Scott Nimrod- I need to add Pages within The master page using frame. So that I can take Frame of the master page in my navigation service and use it to navigate to further pages.